# Xamarin.Forms Caliburn.Micro button click event doen't fire

Tags: xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and try to use Caliburn Micro like i did with WPF.
   But my button click doesn't fire ?

My mainview does show on my connected phone, so far so good!
I know this is very basic but  i can't get it work

```
 <Button x:Name="Connect" Grid.Row="1"  Text="Connect" TextColor="Gainsboro" BackgroundColor="green" />
```

In my view model :

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        IntroLabel = "Caliburn.Micro!";
    }
```

Kind Regards

Johan

Comment: How is your view model named ? mainviewmodel ?

Comment: You can use a command instead, xamarin maybe different from wpf when using Caliburn Micro.

Comment: Yes, my view model is MainViewModel, and i know i can use a command instead, but i became addicted to the ease of Caliburn Micro ! :)

Comment: My team spent quite some time trying to get Caliburn Micro to work with XF. We eventually gave up and moved to ReactiveUI

Comment: Thanks Mouse On Mars for the tip ! Saves me a lot of effort !!